# Form data is empty after using append?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, vue.js

I have a problem to append anything in form data. Its always empty. How can I append image file and some other data?

```
    var data = new FormData();
    fileResult = this.$els.fileIntroImage.files;

    data.append('name',this.property_credentials.name);
    data.append('default_image',this.$els.fileIntroImage.files[0],File);
    console.log('data',data);
```

Comment: Try instead to log: `data.get('name')`

Comment: now i can display it in vue.js, but how can i pass that parameters to laravel controller? when i use like this     this.$http.put('/profile/'+ user_id +'/property/'+ property_id +'/edit', data).then(function(response) { } its empty

Comment: FormData objects are write only and can't be echoed to the console. However are you sure that the data is not being sent at all? check the dev tools of your browser and look at the headers tab for the ajax request, it will show you what was sent, in the request section.

Comment: @Joe "FormData objects are write only and can't be echoed to the console" - amazing. thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Took me a while to get my head around file uploads with Vue.

Here is the methods object on my Vue component:

```
methods: {
    upload(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var self = this;

        var formData = this.gatherFormData();

        this.$http.post('/path/to/upload/method', formData)
        .then(response => {
           //do stuff
        },
        (response) => {
          //show error
        });
    },
    gatherFormData() {
        const data = new FormData();

        data.append('image', this.$refs.image.files[0]);
        data.append('other_field', this.other_field);
        return data;
    }
},
```

This should then function as as a normal file field as far as Laravel is concerned.

Answer (score 0):

It can be logged, you just need to log each item. You can use FormData’s iterator function to do so.

```
var data = new FormData();
data.append('name',this.property_credentials.name);
data.append('default_image',this.$els.fileIntroImage.files[0],File);
data.forEach(el => console.log(el));
```